# WCF IServiceBehavior

Tags: wcf

I have a ServiceBehavior Attribute like this:

```
AdhocAuthenticationAndAuthorisation : IServiceBehavior
{
    public AdhocAuthenticationAndAuthorisation(string systemName, string serviceName)
    {
        //Some code here.
    }
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
    //+ Other interface members.
}
```

This is used for some authentication and authorisation, the Attribute is used to bootstrap some context information that is used later, the context is set up in the Validate method, and works fine when i only use the Attribute on one service in the same apppool. However on a second service(different service interface) in the same apppool the Validate method of the second Attribute is never run if i instantiate the second service, at the same time. If I instantiate the first service and wait 5 seconds and instantiate the other, then the validate method is called.

This has been tested on different bindings and with aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = on or off. The services run on .net and iis 7.5

Does any one know how to solve this issue?